# Handling route with multiple optional parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a filtering method for some products.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/TVs/{type?}/{producer?}', 'Product\AllProducts@getTVs')->where(['type' => '4kTV|curved|lcd|oled|plasma'], ['producer'=>'Samsung'])->name('TVs');
```

And this is the controller function:

```
public function getTVs($type = null, $producer = null)
    {
        $products = DB::table('products')->paginate(16);
        if($type!=null) {
            $products = Product::where('type', $type)->paginate(16);
        }
        if($producer!=null) {
            $products = Product::where('description','like', '%'.$producer.'%')->paginate(16);
        }
        return view('product.TVs', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

If I select the type, the page refreshes and shows the results. Then if i enter the producer, again it works. How can i make the route in such a way, that the order of the optional parameters does not matter and i can filter the results no matter the order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your queries; right now, you're running 3 queries, with `->paginate()` being a closure and triggering a DB call. Try this:

```
$baseQuery = DB::table("products");

if($type){
  $baseQuery->where("type", "=", $type);
}

if($producer){
  $baseQuery->where("description", "like", "%".$producer."%");
}

$products = $baseQuery->paginate(16);
return view("products.TVs"->with(["products" => $products]);
```

As you can see, we add `->where` clauses as required based on the input, and only run a single `->paginate()` right before the `return`. Not this is additive searching, so it's `WHERE ... AND ...` and not `WHERE ... OR ...`; extra logic would be required for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, the search is definitely improved now. But do you know what should i do for the route ? Right now, for TVs/ledTV/Samsung it works well, but what if the user selects first the producer(Samsung) and the url will be something like TVs/Samsung/ledTV ? How can i create the route, so that the order of the optional parameters does not matter ?

Comment: Ah I see, you've got them reversed. You might be better off using a `GET` request with a query string to handle this, like `http://TVs?type=ledTV&producer=Samsung`, as query strings don't care about order. URL Parameters on the other hand correspond to the order they are entered in the function declaration, so `$type` is always first and `$producer` is always second.